# How long is Kitty Pryde using her powers in the future?

Tags: marvel, x-men, x-men-cinematic-universe, x-men-days-of-future-past

In the 2014 film  *X-Men: Days of Future Past*, Wolverine spends roughly 4-5 days in the body of his younger self in 1973. He is sent/held there by Kitty Pryde, who must maintain her concentration while projecting Wolverine's consciousness back in time.

**How long must Kitty remain by Logan's side, projecting his consciousness to the past?** Is Kitty really sitting there using her powers for multiple days, or is there a time dilation effect present?

*Note: For purposes of the question, we'll restrict the discussion to the theatrical version:*

> *where Rogue does not take Kitty's place.*

Comment: I want to say "in realtime" but there's no evidence in the script one way or another. There's a massive jump between Kitty putting Logan under and Logan stabbing Kitty where you can't really tell if any time has passed. They're all wearing the same clothes, but that's no help.

Comment: I would swear that there's somewhere on this site where they establish that someone was able to take her place in shifts, maybe Rogue? It was a deleted scene if I'm recalling correctly.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots - Indeed there was. That's the "Rogue Cut" that Phantom is referring to under the spoiler...

Comment: Relevant: https://youtu.be/uT6YOI6JcRs?t=1m59s

Answer (score 4):

All evidence points to her actions occurring **in realtime**. She specifically states that the past and the present will **"*co-exist*"** for as long as she's able to maintain control.

> **[Kitty](https://web.archive.org/web/20170312063214/http://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=x-men-days-of-future-past):** *... while your mind travels back in time. As long as you're back there, **past and present will continue to coexist**.*

Obviously this begs the question "*[when did she poop](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NobodyPoops)?*" to which the answer is, presumably, "*when the camera wasn't watching her*".